# Defining a Single Template for a Member Function within a Class Template with Both Templates Used in Member Function

Tags: c++, templates, methods, function-templates, class-template

I'm currently learning how templates work in C++. In particular, I'm looking at the single member function templates within class templates. To understand what I mean, code is found below.

```
// foo.h
template<typename A>
class foo {
    template<typename B>
    void boo(B);
};

// foo.cpp
template<typename A>
void foo<A>::boo(B value) {} // compiler error: 'Unknown' type name B

// or if I try this

template<typename B>
void foo<A>::boo(B value) {} // compiler error: Use of undeclared identifier A
```

I'm trying to use two typenames, one from the class template, and one from the single file template, for that specific function. But in those two versions above, I get compiler errors. How would I bypass this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the two sets of template parameters are required to define the [member template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template).

(emphasis mine)

> If the enclosing class declaration is, in turn, a class template, when a member template is defined outside of the class body, **it takes two sets of template parameters: one for the enclosing class, and another one for itself**:

E.g.

```
template<typename A>
template<typename B>
void foo<A>::boo(B value) {}
```

Comment: @MAGEPAC Two sets of template parameters are required; one for the class template, one for the member function template. One set containing two template parameters like `<typename A, typename B>` doesn't fit that.

Comment: Your one would mean a single template with two template parameters, the other one a nested template.